# Encoding & Data Transfer Optimization

Tags: optimization, encoding, data-transfer

I am developing a solution which will include data transfer between mobile phone and server. However, I would like to minimize the quantity of the transferred data.

I was planning to try several types of encoding with TCP/UDP connection and measure the traffic and data loss. Otherwise I believe there already exist some kind of recommendations for protocol development (application layer) for different kind of data (audio, video, text) and network characteristics.

I would be really thankful if anyone provided any link or tip regarding this topic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the compression aspect, Jeff Atwood wrote a [post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001231.html) recently about compression which contained a link to [this page](http://users.elis.ugent.be/~wheirman/compression/index.php) which very nicely shows which compression algorithms/implementations that are best under which conditions when also considering the overhead imposed by doing compression.

For a mobile phone <--> server connection I would guess the speed could be something
like 100-500kbps, and then "7za -mx=9" seems to be the choice that gives the
best compression with least overhead.

For the more general "how to select/develop network protocols" for different scenarios part, this is an very open question and I am not sure if any clear answer can be given.
But for video/audio I suggest looking [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media#Protocol_issues) and I would guess [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) and [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) can be used.